# Issue while reissue of Portugal Railway ticket

Tags: portugal, porto

I booked two tickets from online app from Lisbon to Porto and return on 28th Jul, 2018. Lisbon to Porto journey date was 9th Sep, 2018 and return date is 13th September, 2018. We came to Porto on 9th, September 2018. Then I modify the return date to 12th September 2018 on 10th Sep, 2018. It was shown that I have to pay 19.40 euro to modify whereas it deduct 86.40 euro. Basically they take to and from ticket price again for two tickets (43.20 per person). They take the Lisbon to Porto price again and also the full price of Porto to Lisbon whereas the ticket is modifiable. I am not sure what is the problem. Is there anyone who can guide me how shall I get refund.

Old ticket:
[image: Old Ticket]

New ticket:
[image: New Ticket]

Comment: Where is it said that the ticket is modifiable? I only see that it's "PROMO" and "não reembolsável" which is a very good indication for a **non-modifiable** ticket.

Comment: It's a non refundable but modifiable. If you check, they take Lisbon to Proto price again whereas I already traveled on 9th, Sep. The price of the ticket Porto to Lisbon is around 24 Euro. If it is non refundable then they should cost 48 euro not 86.40 and one more thing, they have given me the option for modify and they show the amount while modify is 19.40 euro will be deducted. Thanks.

Comment: Two situations might be happening: Those promotions are quite recent and the CP website has gone through several changes recently. Assuming your ticket is changeable I wouldn't be surprised that that could be a bug.

Something else that might be happening is that you're paying full fare. I know those promotions exist if you buy in advance. Since you're making a last minute change you might be paying full fare. Try to call the support line (707 210 220). They will probably be able to help.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for replying. I got the refund. They take the whole amount that is 86.40 for two ticket and refund the whole ticket price of my old ticket that is 67 euro for two person to my account. This is the way they operates. Appreciate your valuable comments.

Thanks,
Sudip

Answer (score 1):

**nsn** has a point in the comments: you are paying the full fare now because since the changed return journey is very close, the promo discount doesn't apply anymore.

As described on [the relevant page](https://www.cp.pt/passageiros/en/discounts-benefits/Discounts/compra-antecipada), emphasis theirs:

> If you want to have your ticket reissued and get the discount again
>   (limited to the number of special offer seats on each train), the new
>   journey date has to be at least 5, 8 or more days away (including the
>   purchase date and up to a maximum of 60 days in advance) from when it
>   is reissued.
>
> ...
>
> **Outside these periods and conditions, the ticket is reissued for a ticket without discount and the difference in prices will be charged.**

Note that this doesn't explain why you saw a different number on the site.

Comment: Thanks Marton for you comment. I gone through all the details. I know that I am changing last moment but while modifying they show I have to pay 19.40 euro. It is the rest of the amount (43.20 - 33.50 = 9.7 per person) which is 19.40. But what they did, basically, they add 19.4 with previous 67 euro (already paid) for two person and deduct 86.4 euro from my card. If you check the bold one you have given, there it is properly mentioned "the difference in prices will be charged"

Comment: As others have said, it's best to contact CP to be sure what happened.

Comment: Yes. I will call them or visit rail station directly.

Comment: There is a "PROMO" remark on the new ticket too, so it seems to be a promo tariff too.